# How to delete the cache after logout?

Tags: playframework-2.1

I have a logout function and when i am logged and click the back  button the browser loads the page from the cache but it should reload from the server,help is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible.

It's a client cache, absolutely not related to PlayFramework. Your browser will always get the page from its own cache when you click the back button.

Comment: thanks dude but i searched on google , i tried using cache control -"no store" but it diddn't work even  cache.remove() function is there in play documentation but i am not able to use it, but its not working as well, any idea

Comment: As I said, "back" page is ALWAYS loaded from cache. Your only solution is a complex javascript hack to force reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Julien is right , I solved the issue by checking PLAY_SESSION is availible or not if it is not redirecting to main page.

```
if(getCookies('PLAY_SESSION') == null){ 
  // redirecting to login page
} 

function getCookies(name) {
      var dc = document.cookie;
      var prefix = name + "=";
      var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
      if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
      } else
        begin += 2;
      var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
      if (end == -1)
        end = dc.length;
      return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    }


I hope it will work for You.......
```